# retrieve an image from mongodb and display it using angular7

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, multer

i have uploaded image using `multer` with `disk storage`

in project folder  i have only filename

i.e

```
filename: "1561256874022.jpg"
```

while from mongo i am getting this object

```
destination: "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\project\testing\server\routes/src/assets/images"

encoding: "7bit"

fieldname: "file"

filename: "1561256874022.jpg"

mimetype: "image/jpeg"

originalname: "new.jpg"

path: "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\project\testing\server\routes\src\assets\images\1561256874022.jpg"

size: 1256070

__proto__:Object
```

API post request

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {//destination where images will store
      cb(null, __dirname + '/src/assets/images')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
})
//configuration
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
})

//post data
router.post('/image', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
      var newImage = new Image();
      newImage.file = req.file;
      newImage.description = req.body.description;
      await newImage.save();
      res.status(200).send(newImage);
  }
  catch (e) {
      console.log("failed " + e);
  }
})
```

API get request

```
router.get('/image/:id', (req, res) => {
    Image.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error');
            }
            else {
                console.log("image returned "+data)
                res.json(data);
            }
        })

});
```

compnent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {    

     this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.videoService.editVideo(params.get('id')))).subscribe(res=>{this.video=res});
       }
```

component.html

```
 <img [src]="video.file.filename | safe" alt="not found" width="100px" height="150px">
```

Getting response from api but in browser i have this error

```
core.js:15714 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1561256874022.jpg' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1561256874022.jpg'
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Its not clear from your question.

Comment: excuse me for late response        i am getting this error in browser                                                                   core.js:15714 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1561256874022.jpg'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1561256874022.jpg'

Comment: Please show how are you trying to get the image in our angular code.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti can you help?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(res)` in your subscribe method and show what is the result of that?

Comment: yes i did it and i was getting same result as i got from       console.log("image returned "+data);  in router.get() request

Comment: Can you tell what is it? Is it the same object you posted in your question above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your image is getting saved in images folder, but you are trying to access the image directly in the root folder. Try adding `images/` as . aprefix to your image path, and it should work.

Try :

```
<img [src]="'images/'+video.file.filename | safe" alt="not found" width="100px" height="150px">
```

Comment: I am glad i could help you, and my efforts and time were not wasted at the end :D